# Query and display post from database (Wordpress)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

My problem: I want an archive page for my wordpress blog. Found enough templates but i want to do it on my own. 
How it should look: 
I have some tabs with the years, under each year a list with month, under each month a sublist with every post.
MySQL level i kinda...beginner! 
I managed to query the posts but i don't know how to display them under a list.

"foreach" is giving me headeaches!:(

my code

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb ->get_results("
                SELECT 
                     post_title as post, year(post_date) as year
                FROM wp_posts
                ORDER BY year");

foreach($posts as $post)
    $post=$post_title;

echo $post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens with your code is that you set `$post` every time you iterate through a post object. So what happens, written manually, is this: `$post = "title1"; $post="title2";` etc. Then at the end you echo it which would only show you "title100".

If you'd change your code to this:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    $post=$post_title;
    echo $post;
}
```

It would set `$post = "title1"; echo $post;` which would give you title1, title2, etc.

You can also just remove the variable declaration of $post.

```
foreach($posts as $post)
    echo $post_title;
```

That's the theory of the foreach loop, now you seem to get `$post_title` out of nowhere. Maybe it should be more of `$post->post;` or probably `$post['post'];` Though I do not exactly know how wordpress does this.

EDIT: I checked `$wpdb` out a little, though it remains a little vague, I think it should be `$post['post'];`

Comment: I tried this (with $post['post']) and i still get an error!
http://i.minus.com/irczhZyqCvWwp.PNG

Comment: Okay, and using `$post->post`? Seems like `$posts` is a list of objects in the end. Does foreach cast an associative array to an object, anyone? Try `var_dump($post);` if it still fails.

Comment: Totaly worked! Now i just need to style this to do the things better!